# Creating a class with fields java

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to create a class that represents a person's name and that has fields representing the first name, middle initial, and last name, (also several methods).

When I try to run my code, I receive a `Illegal modifier for the local class Name; only abstract or final is permitted` error and cannot find a way to resolve this. Please help me resolve any errors so that my code will perform the desired (and commented) tasks. Thank you in advance.

```
public class Name {

    String first_name;
    String middle_initial;
    String last_name;

    //constructor that accepts first name, middle initial, and last name as parameters and initializes the Name object's state with those values
    public Name(String first_name, String middle_initial, String last_name) {
        first_name = "John";
        middle_initial = "Q.";
        last_name = "Public";
    }

    //method to return the person's name in first name, middle initial, and last name order.
    public String getNormalOrder() {
        String name = first_name + " " + middle_initial + " " + last_name;
        return name;    
    }

    //method to return the person's name in reversed order: last name, first name, and middle name.
    public String getReverseOrder() {
        String name = last_name + ", " + first_name + " " + middle_initial;
        return name;
    }

    //method to return the full name in first, middle, last order, in String form
    public String toString() {
        return first_name + " " + middle_initial + " " + last_name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        first_name = "John";
        middle_initial = "Q.";
        last_name = "Public";

        getNormalOrder();
        getReverseOrder();
        toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is it a local class, and where's the rest of code? Sidenote: your constructor doesn't initialize the fields to the passed arguments.

Comment: I'm new to this and I haven't learned of any other way (non local way) to create a class. How do I get my constructor to initialize the passed arguments?

Comment: Post your main function.

Comment: You haven't posted your full relevant code. Your class `Name` is defined **inside** another class, and that's the source of the problem. You need to show the class that it's defined inside of.

Comment: More likely, the `Name` class is defined inside a **method**, which is what I think is meant by "local class".  If you really wanted to do this, then you need to learn the correct way to define classes (defining a class inside a method is allowed, but you usually have to have a special reason to do it).  If you didn't want to do this, then you might have misplaced a curly brace.

Comment: I don't particularly want the Name class to be defined inside a method. I wan't it to work in the most conventional way, this is the only way I've (sort of) learned to do it so far. Please let me know how to make the Name class not defined inside a method. I've tried moving around curly braces.. I'll keep trying but please help show me how to do this.

Comment: If you want help, please post your entire code.  If the problem is that this class is defined inside something else, we need to see the whole code so that we can see what it's inside.  We've asked several times to see the whole code.

Comment: 1) You can't access `first_name` within the `static` method. 2) Your constructor isn't actually assigning the object's state to anything. It's just assigning the parameters to hard-coded values. `this.first_name = first_name;` is the correct line within the constructor, however this is not the cause for that error message.

Comment: Please post the edits you would make to the code in order for it to run without errors. I'm new at this and am trying to take people's advice, but I don't know where to start. I don't know how to make the constructor assign object's state, this is the way I've thought to do it. Please show me how to otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start over with a file `Name.java`.

From the top, you can only have one `public class` of the same name as the file it is contained within.

```
public class Name {

}
```

Now, your field definitions are fine.

The constructor, however, should not hard-code the values of "John Q. Public", as this `Name` class can represent *any* instance of `Name`.

Therefore, you need to assign the fields using `this`, which is needed to "qualify" which variable you are using since they are the same variable names. (If you renamed `String first_name` here, to `String fName`, for example, then `first_name = fName` would be possible).

```
public Name(String first_name, String middle_initial, String last_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.middle_initial = middle_initial;
    this.last_name = last_name;
}
```

Then, in the `main` method, you want to make an instance of this object.

```
Name name = new Name("John", "Q.", "Public");
```

That's it.

But if you want to display those values, simply calling your methods isn't correct, as it needs to know *which* `Name` value to call the methods on. You also need to print the String values that are returned to even see them.

```
System.out.println(name.getNormalOrder());
System.out.println(name); // calls name.toString()
```